# Can we edit the related sites section of the FAQ?

Tags: feature-request, site-faq

Can a dev update [this FAQ section about related sites](https://english.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) to include:

> - professional linguists and others with an interest in linguistic research and theory, ask on [Linguistics](http://lingustics.stackexchange.com)
> - literary enthusiasts and those passionate about the written word, ask on [Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Or rather just update the FAQ to point to Linguistics because [Literature is closing][1].


  [1]: http://meta.literature.stackexchange.com/questions/349/literature-is-closing

Answer (score 2):

To be clear, I think that linguistic questions specifically about English should be here at ELU, and questions about languages abstractly and multilingual linguistics questions should go there. Also, to make sure style questions should go in Literature. My edit of yours would be:

- professional linguists and others with an interest in linguistic research and theory involving languages **in addition to English**, ask on Linguistics
- literary enthusiasts and those passionate about **narratives and style of** the written word, ask on Literature